# Jetpack Compose: Error: Could not find or load main class Projects.androidx-master-dev.frameworks

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to try Jetpack compose and following this [README](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/README.md).

```
cd path/to/checkout/frameworks/support/ui/
./studiow
```

While following the guide, when I tried running `./studiow` script in `ui` directory, I am getting this error.

```
Running ./gradlew studio
usage: dirname path
Error: Could not find or load main class Projects.androidx-master-dev.frameworks.support.......prebuilts.fullsdk-darwin.platform-tools.api.api-versions.xml
See also development/diagnose-build-failure for help with build failures in this project.
```

Comment: Works fine on my macOS. Did you follow the [process](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/README.md) here to check out the code.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, but I am facing the error

Comment: Try run `../development/diagnose-build-failure/diagnose-build-failure.sh studiow`

Comment: This didn't work but moving project dir to root somehow worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for sometime.

Previously I have cloned the project inside some directory. `androidx-master-dev` was inside `someDir` `someDir/androidx-master-dev`.

I had to move it back to root `~` Directory and script worked.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to clone the whole ASOP now. Jetpack compose gradle dependencies are availble now. you can use as

```
def compose_version = '0.1.0-dev01'
kapt "androidx.compose:compose-compiler:$compose_version"
kapt "androidx.compose:compose-runtime:$compose_version"
implementation("androidx.ui:ui-core:$compose_version")
implementation("androidx.ui:ui-layout:$compose_version")
implementation("androidx.ui:ui-framework:$compose_version")
implementation("androidx.ui:ui-material:$compose_version")
implementation("androidx.ui:ui-foundation:$compose_version")
implementation("androidx.ui:ui-text:$compose_version")
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but that's not the question. I still wanted to use ASOP.